# SQL Event Calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Event Calendar that I am trying to create in SQL.The issue is I can not pivot the events like I do the dates. Is there a way to do two pivots or something similiar so that the events line up under the dates.

Here is the table before a pivot

```
YearNum MonthName   week_number DayNum  DayofWeek   EventStart  EventSubject    EventLocation   EventDate
2018    August                  33  14  Tuesday         NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    August                  33  15  Wednesday       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    August                  33  16  Thursday        13:00   Dan's Birthday  EC-E    2018-08-16
2018    August                  33  17  Friday          NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    August                  33  18  Saturday        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    August                  34  19  Sunday          NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018    August                  34  20  Monday          NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

After the pivot, this is how it looks

[image]

Here is the SQL Query that I am currently working with:

```
SELECT MonthName, YearNum, Sunday, Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday, EventStart, EventSubject, EventLocation, EventDate
FROM 
(
SELECT        CalendarDates.YearNum, CalendarDates.MonthName, DATEPART(WEEK, CalendarDates.StandardDate) AS week_number, CalendarDates.DayNum, 
                         CalendarDates.DayofWeek, EventList.EventStart, EventList.EventSubject, EventList.EventLocation, EventList.EventDate
FROM            (SELECT        EventStart, EventSubject, EventLocation, EventDate
                          FROM            EventList AS EventList_1) AS EventList RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         CalendarDates ON EventList.EventDate = CalendarDates.StandardDate
WHERE        (CalendarDates.MonthNum = '8') AND (CalendarDates.YearNum = '2018')
)
pivotDates
PIVOT (MIN(DayNum) FOR DayofWeek IN (Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday)) AS Pivots
```

This is how the output should look like
[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Is the pivot how it looks now or how you want it to look? What happens if there is more than one event in a week?

Comment: Don't post images, post sample data and expected results as `text`. if you really want to go the whole hog, post your sample data in the form of a `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement.

Comment: The pivot is how it looks now The final results would be the event within the date on the calendar.

Comment: "The event within the date on the calendar" could mean anything.   Paste a desired result set into your question.

Comment: Why did I get down votes. How in more detail can I explain the issue?

Comment: I think you should concat `DayNum`,  `EventStart` etc into one value (for example `AS EventInfo` as use `MIN(EventInfo)` in the pivot. Somehow you should "de-concat" this value in the UI to format the parts separately, for example by pipe-separating the parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem could be better solved in the presentation layer, as the SQL does a good job on computing/filtering data, but not in user interface.

Anyways, try this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth   INT = 8,
        @CurrentYear    INT = 2018

;WITH   RawData AS  -- Your original appointment dates
(
        SELECT  CAST('2018-08-16' AS DATE)  Date, 
                CAST('13:00'      AS TIME)  Start, 
                'Someone birthday'          Subject, 
                'Location'                  Location 
),      AllMonthDays AS -- list of all days in the filtered month
(
        SELECT  CAST(CAST(@CurrentYear  AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
                     CAST(@CurrentMonth AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATE) Date UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(D, +1, Date)
        FROM    AllMonthDays
        WHERE   MONTH(DATEADD(D, +1, Date)) = @CurrentMonth
),      CalendarData AS -- Adds the weekday name, week numbering and appointment data
(
        SELECT      AllMonthDays.Date,
                    DATEPART(WEEK   , AllMonthDays.Date) WeekNumber,
                    DATENAME(DW     , AllMonthDays.Date) WeekdayName,
                    NULLIF(CONCAT(
                        CAST(RawData.Start AS CHAR(5)), ' ', 
                        RawData.Subject, '@ ', RawData.Location), ' @ ') Appointment
        FROM        AllMonthDays
        LEFT JOIN   RawData
                ON  RawData.Date = AllMonthDays.Date
),      CalendarFormat AS   -- PIVOT the data, putting the weekdays as columns
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    CalendarData 
        PIVOT
        (   --MIN(Date) FOR         -- uncomment this to a better understanding
            MIN(Appointment) FOR    -- weird part: using MIN in a text column
            WeekdayName IN
            (   [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],
                [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday]
            )
        ) p
)
SELECT      MIN(WeekNumber ) [WeekNumber],
            MIN([Sunday]   ) [Sunday], 
            MIN([Monday]   ) [Monday], 
            MIN([Tuesday]  ) [Tuesday], 
            MIN([Wednesday]) [Wednesday], 
            MIN([Thursday] ) [Thursday], 
            MIN([Friday]   ) [Friday], 
            MIN([Saturday] ) [Saturday]
FROM        CalendarFormat
GROUP BY    WeekNumber  -- suppress duplications
ORDER BY    WeekNumber
```